# need the "IT" removed from the SH - CSS not behaving - I'm still very green - help please

Tags: css

GRRRR....  I've got this page at:  http://winteradagency.com/Arvin/advantages/advantages.htm
It's not showing the #content div and it's not obeying the margin-top=20px on the container div.  I've used a scalable background using a .bg class.  It still works in IE^.

The main page is up and running and looks pretty good. Just take out everything after Arvin in the URL.

Any idears?

I won't be back for 3 hours so my response may be delayed.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

~Andrea

Comment: That's an extremely useful subject line.  Very searchable.

Comment: open your page in Firefox and examine it with the plugin called Firebug. You'll be able to see exactly what styles are being applied.  When I looked, it was complaining that the styles.css file could not be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

Add

```
position: absolute;
```

to #content

Longer answer:

Install firebug like @dnagirl says.  This will allow you to manipulate styles and even the DOM dynamically.  There are a bunch of tutorials about how to use it, I would start with [this screencast](http://polymorphicpodcast.com/podcast/video/firebug-and-jquery/)